# Run portable firefox remotely

Tags: java, selenium

I need to run **portable** Firefox using RemoteWebDriver, but facing the problem:

Here is code for a local run which works perfectly:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(
                     new FirefoxBinary(
                         new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
                         "/tools/FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.exe")),profile);       
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

How can I run it on local server? With something like:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `RemoteWebDriver`, There are two ways to set `firefox` binary as below :

- You need to set `FirefoxBinary` into `DesiredCapabilities` as :

  ```
  FirefoxBinary bin = new FirefoxBinary(
                   new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
                   "/tools/FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.exe"));
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, bin);

  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
  driver.get("http://google.com");
  ```
- You need to run `selenium-server-standalone-x.jar` with `-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin` property which will point to `firefox` binary path as :

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="path/to/firefox binary"
  ```

  Now you can instantiate `RemoteWebDriver` with `firefox` as :

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
  driver.get("http://google.com");
  ```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting??

Comment: Sorry, my bad, second case works perfectly. For the first one:WedDriverException : java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String when initializing RemoteWebDriver

Comment: @user1274184 But in my case both options work perfect...I think problem other than that because here is no java.util.HashMap present..:)

Comment: Same problem as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260364/weddriverexception-java-util-hashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string-when-i Says something about incompatible versions. Thanks a lot.